# cURL error 58: SSL: Can't load the certificate "..." and its private key: OSStatus -25299 on Mac

Tags: php, macos, curl, homebrew, commoncrypto

The code is working fine on Ubuntu vagrant box, but on local MacOs it does not load sertificates saying

```
cURL error 58: SSL: Can't load the certificate "..." and its private key: OSStatus -25299
```

I researched that Mac has a point of supporting the OS X native API instead of OpenSSL.

And I need to convert a **pem + cert** to **pkcs12** like that.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in ./client.crt -inkey ./client.pem -out client.p12
```

But this is not working for me because my PHP server is on Ubuntu and I don't want to break what is working. My task is to make it work on Mac.

I would rather install curl with openssl support. I tried this:

```
$ brew uninstall curl
$ brew install curl --with-openssl
$ brew link curl --force
$ curl --version
```

But it did not solve the problem.

Please tell me what am I did wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Related to bug https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/283

Answer (score 1):

installing curl via brew and with openssl support as outlined in the question is the correct approach. however you need to explicitly call it from its install dir `/usr/local/opt/curl/bin/curl -v -k --key..` as brew wont link it to /usr/local as stated on install

```
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/curl/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/curl/include
For pkg-config to find this software you may need to set:
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/curl/lib/pkgconfig
```

Comment: can you line out where to set this paths? 
I do not understand the topic where to do it and what is to do...

Comment: @novski to permanently set the `PATH` variable, add it to your shells rc file. that might be `~/.zshrc` or more standard/likely`~/.bashrc`
if you need openssl in some software project you want to build, you have to set the `LDFLAGS` `CPPFLAGS` and maybe `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` in the build tool. otherwise ignore them