# POST request using guzzle6 with pfx-certificate

Tags: guzzle6

Is it possible to create a POST request using guzzle6 which has .pfx-certificate attached to it?

The documention only mentions pem-format: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#cert

Comment: Just convert the [`.pfx` file to `.pem`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413646/converting-pfx-to-pem-using-openssl).

Comment: I tried this but using pem format didn't work out in my context. Apparently there are some problems with mac os x and pem certificate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40712352/curl-error-58-ssl-cant-load-the-certificate-and-its-private-key-osstat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the documentation at http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#cert doesn't mention it, it seems to be possible to also use pfx-format with guzzle.

Comment: i tried using the .p12 [personal information exchange] file and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

PFX certificates are used for "mutual authentications", that means, the PFX is generated with your local private key and the remote public cert.

To generate a PFX key you run:

```sh
openssl pkcs12 -inkey your_privkey.pem -in remote_pub.cert -export -out mixed.pfx
```

To make a request using the PFX cert, you can:

```php
$api = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => $baseUrl,
    'cert'     => 'path/to/mixed.pfx',
    'curl'     => [CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE => 'P12'], // to define it's a PFX key
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> this will work in drupal 8 too

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

 // Base URI is used with relative requests

$client = new Client([
   
        'base_uri' => 'https://www.google.com',
        'cert'     => 'pathtopfxflie/nameof.pfx',
        'curl'     => [CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE => 'P12']]);
$response = $client->request('METHOD', 'api path',['headers' => ['Employer' => 100]]);

//get status code using $response->getStatusCode();

$body = $response->getBody();
$arr_body = json_decode($body);
```